How to execute multi attribute selection jq command on a external json file from windows cmder
I'm attempting to use windows cmder to execute jq commands for command-line JSON processor to transform and output existing JSON files I have saved.
Given the the sample json
[
  {
    "firstName": "Doug",
    "accountNumber": "123456",
    "language": "en_US",
    "brand": "Tide",
    "country": "US",
    "branch": "MIA",
    "city": "Miami",
    "state": "FL",
    "zipCode": "33133"
  }
]

While I am able to output the files for simple filter output such the following:
cat sample.json | jq .[] --color-output

or
jq .[] sample.json --color-output

or a filter on a single attribute like country (any nested items within whenever present with dot notation)
jq .[].country sample.json --color-output

Unfortunately, I am unable to perform any of the more complex actions such as extracting specific attributes or filtering for specific using online resources like jqplay which allow me to use
.[] | {accountNumber:.accountNumber, brand:.brand, city:.city, state:.state}

When I try to perform this same type of command that worked on jqplay within cmder to transform the sample json data to display with only certain fields, I receive the following error.
jq '.[] | {accountNumber:.accountNumber, brand:.brand, city:.city, state:.state}' sample.json

error message: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
I looked through a few jq documentation resources such as the jq manual and jq cheatsheet and while I saw examples of how it suggest extracting attributes, I have not been able to get such filtering/transforming to work when referring to any of my sample JSON files like this but the files read in fine for the single attribute selection example I illustrated earlier. I imagine if I've written incorrect syntax for cmder reading local or remote JSON files it will be easy for someone here to identify and help correct. I really want to be able to this on windows cmder like most things and not powershell or anything like that.

Try with double quotes instead.

Using double quotes works great. Thank you. However, even with double quotes I experience the same error when combining conditions  jq ".[] | select(.city='Miami') | {accountNumber:.accountNumber, brand:.brand, city:.city, state:.state}" sample.json
Is there some escaping needed?

Yes, \"Miami\", not 'Miami'. This is Powershell syntax though, can't you configure Cmder to use bash instead?

From cmder, after researching I was able to launch new consoles for both {bash::mintty}  and {Powershell::PowerShell as Admin} using ctrl+T (just like I tried with Git Bash) and re-tried  "Miami" from both and it didn't filter but just displayed the all results. I added a record with another city city=Atlanta. I'm at a lost for why it didn't filter but now displays both records.

I found the issue. I needed double equal sign instead of a single equal to match city.
You were correct with the escape of double quotes and when to escape them.

Some things that might help:

Single quote your commands
Use map() instead of .[] for nested or complicated commands
{key} is the same as {key:.key}

jq '.[]|{accountNumber,brand,city,state}' sample.json
# is the same as
jq 'map({accountNumber,brand,city,state})[]' sample.json

Example showing when to use map() over .[]:
map returns an array so you can pipe another map command right after it
jq 'map({accountNumber,city,state})|map(.+{location:"\(.city), \(.state)"})' sample.json


The comments aided me in solving my question.
I learned there were different command-line environments requiring slight different syntax for extracting specific attributes or handling filter selections.

cmder.exe (or standard command prompt)
jq ".[] | select(.city == \"Miami\") | {accountNumber, brand, city, state}" sample.json

mintty.exe (Git Bash or Similar)
jq '.[] | select(.city == "Miami") | {accountNumber, brand, city, state}' sample.json

Powershell.exe
jq '.[] | select(.city == \"Miami\") | {accountNumber, brand, city, state}' sample.json


Also, while not a complex nested I still tried using the map function and saw it worked the same as a commenter said and better prep for additional complex mapping later.
Using map() over .[]:

cmder.exe (or standard command prompt)
jq "map({accountNumber,brand,city,state})[] | select(.city == \"Miami\")" sample.json

mintty.exe (Git Bash or Similar)
jq 'map({accountNumber,brand,city,state})[] | select(.city == "Miami")' sample.json

Powershell.exe
jq 'map({accountNumber,brand,city,state})[] | select(.city == \"Miami\")' sample.json


